# xslt to create dynamic table with customizable headers

Tags: xslt, xhtml

I would like to transform an XML document using xslt with a set of row nodes and column nodes into an xhtml table.

The column nodes define data about the associated row attribute. For example, the first column node specifies that the ID attribute of the Row node should be hidden (i.e. not show up in the table). The Caption element of the Column node defines what the column header text should be.

I've seen solutions where you know the attributes that you want to turn into columns ahead of time, but I'm not sure how to use the relevant column data to format the headers

Input:

```
<TableData>
    <Columns>
         <Column Name="ID" Hidden="true" />
         <Column Name="Name" Caption="Item Name" />
         <Column Name="Desc" Caption="Item Description" />
    </Columns>
    <Rows>
         <Row ID="0" Name="A" />
         <Row ID="1" Name="B" Desc="Some description"/>
         <Row ID="3" Name="C" />
    </Rows>
</TableData>
```

Desired output would be a table in (x)html something like this:

```
Item Name      | Item Description
--------------------------------------
A              |      
B              | Some Description
C              |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="RowAttribsByName" match="Row/@*"
      use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', name())"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vColNames" select=
  "/*/Columns/*[not(@Hidden = 'true')]/@Name"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="Columns/*"/>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Rows/Row"/>
  </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Column[not(@Hidden = 'true')]">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="@Caption"/></td>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Row">
  <tr>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$vColNames">
     <xsl:with-param name="pRowId"
          select="generate-id()"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Column/@*">
  <xsl:param name="pRowId"/>

  <td width="50%">
    <xsl:value-of select=
      "key('RowAttribsByName',
           concat($pRowId, '|', .)
           )
    "/>
  </td>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<TableData>
    <Columns>
        <Column Name="ID" Hidden="true" />
        <Column Name="Name" Caption="Item Name" />
        <Column Name="Desc" Caption="Item Description" />
    </Columns>
    <Rows>
        <Row ID="0" Name="A" />
        <Row ID="1" Name="B" Desc="Some description"/>
        <Row ID="3" Name="C" />
    </Rows>
</TableData>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td>Item Description</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50%">A</td>
      <td width="50%"/>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50%">B</td>
      <td width="50%">Some description</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50%">C</td>
      <td width="50%"/>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What if each Column had a Sort attribute that I wanted to sort the columns on? I can see where to apply an xsl:sort to the apply-templates for the headers, but how would I get the individual cells to sort correctly?

Comment: @pickles: what would that sort attribute mean? It isn't convenient to define a new question within comments -- please, think it all over and ask a new question. In 8 hours I will have had my sleep and will be able to respond to your new question. Good night for now.

Comment: @pickles: You don't really need to ask a new question for that, it's a fairly easy addition to this answer; just add an `<xsl:sort select='@Name' />` as a child of the `<xsl:apply-templates select="Rows/Row" />` instruction to sort by the `Name` attribute. Obviously, select whatever is appropriate for what you want to sort on to sort by something other than `@Name`.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  Very nice! it works for me. But i have question that  I want to check here that If column is "Name" then i need to sort it. so  how i check that column is "Name" or "Desc" then i will perform my step.

Comment: @MayurBorad, You need to ask this as a question -- not a comment.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, i have create new quetion, Pls can u give me you suggetion -   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030044/xslt-creating-dynamic-grid