# XSLT - Creating Dynamic Grid with single XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am creating dynamic table(grid) using xslt,

I am beginner in XSLT, I have also asked question before here it is ***[XSLT - Creating Dynamic Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030044/xslt-creating-dynamic-grid)***
please refer it, 
On Above Question I am using 2 XML for Columns And Rows , But Here i am trying only one XML(Rows).
You can find XSLT on above Question with 2 XML Section.

**XML Data :**

```
<TableData>        
    <Rows>
        <Row ID="0" Name="A" Link-Name="Yes" Hide-ID="Yes" Sort-Name="Yes"/>
        <Row ID="1" Name="B" Desc="Some description" Link-Name="Yes" Hide-ID="Yes" Sort-Name="Yes"/>
        <Row ID="3" Name="C" Link-Name="Yes" Hide-ID="Yes" Sort-Name="Yes"/>
    </Rows>
</TableData>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <a onclick="javascript:SortColumn('Item Name')">Item Name</a>
            </td>
            <th>
                Item Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%">
                <a onclick="javascript:OpenDifferentPage('A','0')">A</a>
            </td>
            <td width="50%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%">B</td>
            <td width="50%">Some description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%">C</td>
            <td width="50%"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am beginner in XSLT,

I want to check here that If "Link-Name" attribute ="yes" then i need to display Data in between anchor tag(Name).

I am create many complex functionality on this column. So here can i made template for particular attributes of column which is used to display on grid others attribute are for Data purpose(**Column are 15 but it depend on user selection, if user select 8 column for display and also it must maintain ORDER of attributes**)
I am ready to create pre-defined template for all Columns.
So Is it possible for me?

Thank you for your anticipation

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what are you asking exactly / what is your problem

Comment: In simple way, I need a Expected Output from XML Data.

Comment: You say "Column are 15 but it depend on user selection" but how do you know what the columns are if they don't appear in the XML?

Comment: Columns are 15, I have set option that user can select theirs needed columns and also set order of columns in another module which is stored on database. I am getting XML from Database. If user have select 5 columns, XML(Rows) will have 5 columns attribute and others attribute like "Hide-ID" also available in XML(Other attributes are set for other functionality). I know Name of all 15 columns in XSLT which is fixed but Order of it i don't know in XSLT. Let me know if u get this.

Comment: In your input XML, all three rows have Link-Name="Yes", so why do expect to only have an anchor for the row with Name="A"? In particular, why is there a difference in output between rows "A" and "C"? Apart from their Name and ID they are identical...

Comment: @Ben: I have given here prototype, On behalf it, i will make another functionality with reference with "Link-Name" attribute.

Comment: Part of the problem is you have no code, just an input file and an output file. Perhaps if you showed us the XSLT code you've written we might be able to help?